# React create constants file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constants

How to create constants file like: key - value in ReactJs,

```
ACTION_INVALID = "This action is invalid!"
```

and to use that in other components

```
errorMsg = myConstClass.ACTION_INVALID;
```

Comment: A global constants?  Are you bundling?

Comment: I use browsersync for server

Answer (score 163, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I got your question but if I did it should be quite simple:

From my understanding you just want to create a file with constants and use it in another file.

fileWithConstants.js:

```
export const ACTION_INVALID = "This action is invalid!"
export const CONSTANT_NUMBER_1 = 'hello I am a constant';
export const CONSTANT_NUMBER_2 = 'hello I am also a constant';
```

fileThatUsesConstants.js:

```
import * as myConstClass from 'path/to/fileWithConstants';

const errorMsg = myConstClass.ACTION_INVALID;
```

If you are using react you should have either webpack or packager (for react-native) so you should have babel which can translate your use of export and import to older js.

Comment: export const is invalid

Comment: What do you mean? I assume you use older versions of js, in that case try exports.ACTION_INVALID instead of export const and use require('path/to/fileWithConstants').ACTION_INVALID instead of import.

Comment: ```events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
SyntaxError: D:/constants.jsx: Unexpected token (2:11)
class Constants extends React.Component{
    export const ACTION_INVALID = "This action is invalid!"
    export const CONSTANT_NUMBER_1 = 'hello I am a constant';
    export const CONSTANT_NUMBER_2 = 'hello I am also a constant';
}```

Comment: You don't have to create a class that extends Component to use a bunch of constants. Just do like my example. create a file with only one line: export const ACTION_INVALID = "blablabla";      And use it in your other file by using: import * as myConstClass from 'path/to/file';

Comment: No I got other errors. This is not the way. I use jsx and ES2015

Comment: @Monadsarelike...Hey, thanks for your answer, I was banging my head against a wall to get this working! I have about 30 consts I need to export from one file, I'm wondering is there a way to group them all in an array instead of having "export const" for each one individually?

Comment: @Monadsarelike... What does the `*` represent in the import statement? Why can't I just do `import myConstClass from 'path'`?

Comment: @justColbs Its about the difference between `export default` and `export`.
If you want to use export default do it like this:
`export default {CONSTANT_NUMBER_1:  'hello I am a constant', CONSTANT_NUMBER_2: 'hello I am also a constant'}`
Here I created an object with 2 different fields which represent the constants.
To use it you would do:
`import whateverNameYouWant from 'path/to/fileWithConstants'`

Comment: @justColbs: If you don't want to type `myConstClass` all the time (which, by convention, I'm pretty sure should be with a capital 'M' anyhow), see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46815846/1450294

Comment: The accepted solution didn't work for me. This one works just perfectly. Maybe I'm missing out on something. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @Monadsarelike... Is there is any way by using it I import a constant file once like in app.js and then use it in any component without importing a constant file? I know pass data as a parameter, but it's not a good way. I am using nextjs(https://nextjs.org/docs) in my project

Answer (score 41):

Expanding on [Monad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39036632/1450294), for situations where you don't want to type `myConstClass` all the time:

fileWithConstants.js:

```
export const ACTION_INVALID = "This action is invalid!"
export const CONSTANT_NUMBER_1 = 'hello I am a constant';
export const CONSTANT_NUMBER_2 = 'hello I am also a constant';
```

fileThatUsesConstants.js:

```
import { ACTION_INVALID } from 'path/to/fileWithConstants';

const errorMsg = ACTION_INVALID;
```

(Also, if Monad's way works better for you, I believe the convention is for 'MyConstClass' to start with a capital letter, since it's acting like a class in code.)

Answer (score 39):

You can simply create an object for your constants:

```
const myConstClass = {
    ACTION_INVALID: "This action is invalid!"
}
```

And then use it.

If you are bundling, you can `export` this object and then `import` for each component file.

Comment: but this way, you still **CAN** change the values. you just can't change the object myConstClass is pointing to.

Comment: @Bat You can just use Object.freeze(...) to make it a shallow immutable object. Nested maps, if any, will also need to be frozen similarly.

Comment: @Debajit Not sure if it was around back in 2018. Thank you! I actually haven't touched React.js in years and have switched fields a while ago lol.

Answer (score 14):

One way to do that (not so different from other answers though) is to create a bare constants.js file and add your constants there.

```
module.exports = Object.freeze({
  ACTION_INVALID: 'This action is invalid',
  ACTION_VALID: 'Some other action',
});
```

Then you can import it

```
import ConstantsList from './constants';
```

and use

```
console.log(ConstantsList.ACTION_INVALID)
```

As the name suggests, [Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) freezes objects and stops anyone from changing the values. Please note: if the values are objects themselves they are changeable (unless they are also frozen)

Answer (score 1):

In nodejs enviroment, when using absolute path, there already is deprecated "constants" and it may conflict with yours, so it's better to create either a folder and put your constants there or create a file with name **consts**.

Your constants should look like that, use `Object.freeze` so that constants are never changed by a side effect. You should use `Object.freeze` for every object.

```js
export const ACTION_INVALID = "This action is invalid!"
export const FILE_TYPES = Object.freeze({
  IMAGE: Object.freeze(["JPEG", "PNG"]),
  VIDEO: Object.freeze(["MP4", "M4V", "MOV", "3GP", "3G2", "WMV", "ASF", "AVI", "FLV", "MKV", "WEBM"])
})
```