# Hardcoded strings/static contents in React/Redux app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am optimizing a react/redux app and I wondered if there is the best practice to store and render hardcoded strings in such an app? Some of my components are using the same text and if there is a text change I will have to search all for all text occurrences. Would be better to have central location. I mean some static contents that y you do not want to put into state.

I would store all texts in a json object but I assume there must be a better way.

could anyone share his/her experience? any helpful tools or packages?

thank a lot for your answers!

Comment: Please share more context about these hardcoded strings. Are they represent Redux action types or something else?

Comment: @KaloyanKosev I meant the static content that you would not put into state

Comment: I still don't understand. Please specify an use-case or an example. Otherwise the topic is too broad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React create constants file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036457/react-create-constants-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thank you for comments. In case, someone looks for nice solution this is - https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl

Requires some setup though but does what I wanted through making first steps towards internalization of the app.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing special here really regarding react or redux, you could just create a constants file...

```
export const VAR_NAME = "this is some text";
export const ANOTHER_VAR = "something else";
```

then when you want to use, simply:

```
import { ANOTHER_VAR } from 'path/to/constants/file';
```